# How can I check for a python c_ubyte_Array type without checking the type(x)__name__ string?

Tags: python, ctypes

Here is the sample code:

```py
class Mystruct(LittleEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('field1', c_ubyte * 5),
    ]

    def to_dict(self):
        d = dict((field, getattr(self, field)) for field, _ in self._fields_)
        for field in d:
            # print(field, type(d[field]))
            if type(d[field]).__name__.startswith(('c_ubyte_Array')):
                d[field] = ''.join( [ f'{x:02x}' for x in d[field] ])
        return d

x = Mystruct.from_buffer_copy(b'AAAAAAAAA')
print(x.to_dict())
```

As you can see I am checking the type by string.startswith rather than isinstance etc because the type changes depending on the c_ubyte_Array_n length, above is c_ubyte_Array_5 (some of the records I use have different lengths, e.g. c_ubyte_Array_32 etc)

I just cannot figure out what class to check.

Comment: `type(X)._type_ is c_ubyte`.

Comment: Brill it works - thanks

Comment: excellent! @jasonharper can you write that up as an Answer?

Answer (score 0):

Edited as suggested by comments:

```py
class Mystruct(LittleEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('field1', c_ubyte * 5),
        ('field2', c_ubyte),
    ]

    def to_dict(self):
        d = dict((field, getattr(self, field)) for field, _ in self._fields_)
        for field in d:
            if isinstance(d[field], Array) and d[field]._type_ is c_ubyte:
                d[field] = ''.join( [ f'{x:02x}' for x in d[field] ])
        return d

x = Mystruct.from_buffer_copy(b'AAAAAAAAA')
print(x.to_dict())

isinstance(x.field1, (Array, c_ubyte))
```

Comment: What was `if isinstance(d[field], (Array, c_ubyte)):` intended to do? Because I don't think it's doing that.

Comment: If you were trying to check "is this an array of c_ubyte", well, it doesn't do that. It checks if `d[field]` is an instance of `Array` *or* an instance of `c_ubyte`. *All* ctypes arrays pass this check. A `c_ubyte` field *won't* pass, though, because ctypes will automatically convert to Python `int` when you retrieve the field value.

Comment: You probably want `isinstance(d[field], Array) and d[field]._type_ is c_ubyte`.